# jquery expose gets cut off on scroll - while using simple overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, overlay, jquery-tools

No idea how to fix this, the expose transparency covers only your original view. When you scroll down the expose is cut off.

Do i need to add something that relates to overflow or sizing here?

```
<script>
// What is $(document).ready ? See: http://flowplayer.org/tools/using.html#document_ready


$("img[rel]").overlay({expose: '#000'});

});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to link to something that is SFW.

Comment: You need to edit your question so that people don't have to click off-site to answer it.  If you wish to illustrate what you're talking about take a snapshot of what the issue is and add that.

Comment: You are using jQuery Tools and you should have mentioned that in your question.  jQuery Tools is out of date, poorly supported, not in keeping with traditional jQuery plugin methods, and probably a dead project.  There are so many better jQuery overlay and lightbox plugins out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think you want to set "fixed" to false, like this:

```
$("img[rel]").overlay({mask: '#000', fixed: false});
```

Then your overlay will scroll with your page.

Comment: For a non-jQueryTools overlay, anything but `position: fixed;` will cause the problem as described by the OP.  So maybe he needs `fixed: true;` but you never know with jQT.

Comment: No, this works for jQT (for me at least; I was having the same problem, and I was using jQT).